# executing a custom init script for bash --login -i for example to change to a custom directory from a shortcut

Tags: bash

Right now I'm using MSysGit on Windows 7, which is started from a .bat file, which itself calls `bash.exe --login -i` to start a shell. At which point it executes the .bashrc file (among others) in the user's home directory. I use this script to setup the environment and `cd` to a starting directory.

This all works fine.  What I would like is to change the .bat file in some way so that bash will execute a custom script at startup so that in that script i could perform a different initialization and cd to a different starting directory. Then I could have two separate .bat files calling each script, then I could make a shortcut to both on the desktop and start whichever I want.

The thing that I'm not sure how to do, is get bash to run a custom init script on startup. Currently the command MSysGit uses is `bash.exe --login -i`. Is there any way I can modify this to get it to use a custom file? I tried `bash.exe --login --rcfile 01.txt -i` but that didn't work. Likewise nothing else I tried worked either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it without `--login`:

```
bash.exe --rcfile 01.txt -i
```

Comment: ok, that partly worked.  it executed 01.txt but it didn't setup the shell properly.  MSysGit seems to need that.  anyway to have both?

Comment: @Coder: You may need to source `/etc/profile` or another file from your `01.txt`.

Comment: Ok that seems to have worked.  Thanks!!  Can you explain what --login does and how it's related to /etc/profile briefly?  Am i correct in assuming that all --login does is run /etc/profile?  Is /etc/profile just a standard init script?  What does it typically set up.

Comment: @Coder: See `man bash`. A login shell handles exiting a little differently. It may process a logout script when it exits and it may SIGHUP its jobs if an option is set to do so. `/etc/profile` is a shell script that could do almost anything. You will have to look at it to see what.

Comment: unfortunately i don't have the man command in MSYSGit.  Can you clarify a bit what you mean by "exiting a little differently"?  Do you think that this workaround might break MSysGit?

Comment: @Coder: Here's the [`man` page](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html) and the full [reference manual](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html). Here's a direct link to the section on [Bash Startup Files](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC71). The next sentence in my previous comment describes what "exiting a little differently" means.

Comment: --login definitely does something important; I'm using Cygwin to develop Android apps and the ndk-build script spits out lots of errors without --login. However, --login changes the current directory to ~ and I wish I could avoid that behavior. `.bash_profile` and `.profile` don't appear to contain a `cd` command...