# Changing bash prompt in new bash

Tags: bash, shell, prompt

When I create an new bash process, the prompt defaults to a very simple one.
I know I can edit .bashrc etc to change this, but is there a way of passing the prompt with the bash command?

thanks!

Comment: You can set [`PS1`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) in your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Just adding my formulation of this question, as I had a hard time finding it: "override PS1 at bash startup from command line"; also related [executing a custom init script for bash --login -i for example to change to a custom directory from a shortcut - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203604/executing-a-custom-init-script-for-bash-login-i-for-example-to-change-to-a-cu)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The prompt is defined by the PS1, PS2, PS3 and PS4 environment variables. So, e.g. the following will start a new bash with the prompt set to "foo: ":

```
PS1="foo: " bash --norc
```

The `--norc` is required to suppress processing of the initialization files, which would override the `PS1` variable.

Comment: +1 if you define PS1 in the .bash_profile instead of .bashrc, you don't even need the "--norc" option.

Comment: Thanks! @glennjackman: I don't want it in every shell, I want to have a test environment that I can call. When I am in this test environment, the prompt should indicate this.

Comment: If you have something like a git aware prompt, you'll also need to ensure `PROMPT_COMMAND` is empty.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem - I'd like to startup a temporary bash from the command line; and while most other environment variables remain; those that are sourced from `~/.bashrc` are kind of difficult to override - especially if you, like me, would actually like to keep the `~/.bashrc` you already have (and aliases inside, etc.) - save for the `PS1` prompt.

Here is something that works for me (note that `--init-file` is a synonym/alias for `--rcfile`):

```
bash --rcfile <(cat ~/.bashrc ; echo 'PS1="\[\033[0;33m\]\u@HELLO:\W\$\[\033[00m\] "')
```

Basically, the bracket/less-than + parenthesis idiom `<()` starts up `bash` process substitution; everything echoed to stdout inside the parenthesis will end up in a temporary file, `/dev/fd/<n>`. So we first cat the contents of out `~/.bashrc`; then we simply add a `PS1` set command at end, (which effectively overrides) - this ends up in `/dev/fd/<n>`; and `bash` then uses `/dev/fd/<n>` for the new `rcfile`.

This is how it behaves:

```
user@pc:tmp$ TESTVAR="testing" bash --rcfile <(cat ~/.bashrc ; echo 'PS1="\[\033[0;33m\]\u@HELLO:\W\$\[\033[00m\] "')
user@HELLO:tmp$ test-alias-tab-completion ^C
user@HELLO:tmp$ echo $TESTVAR 
testing
user@HELLO:tmp$ exit
exit
user@pc:tmp$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an environment variable, and then use that environment variable in your prompt in .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the profiles, but don't want to hardcode all the possible paths to source them from, then a more generic somewhat shell-agnostic solution is:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="(customize) $PS1"; PROMPT_COMMAND=' $SHELL
```

With the caveat of only working as long as the default profiles don't set `PROMPT_COMMAND`. But that's more likely than them not setting `PS1`.